# Latent Class Growth Analysis - Issue assigning each observation to a class

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using the lcmm package in R to model longitudinal data. I'm trying to use the postprob function to get the posterior probabilities of the latent classes, and then use these to assign each observation to a class. However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
 "Error in $<-.data.frame(tmp, groups, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : replacement has 39964 rows, data has 40000".
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```
#install.packages("lcmm")
#devtools::install_github("hlennon/LCTMtools")

library(lcmm)
library(LCTMtools)

data( bmi_long, package = "LCTMtools" )
data <- data.frame(bmi_long)

data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)
data$x <-data$age
data$y<-as.numeric(data$bmi)
data <-subset(data, select=c("id", "x", "y"))

m1 <- lcmm(fixed=y ~ x, subject = 'id', data = data)
summary(m1)
postprob(m1)
data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)
groups <- as.data.frame(m1$pprob[,1:2])
data$groups <- factor(groups$class[sapply(data$id, function(x) which(groups$id==x))])
```